# Python regular expression finding a word

Tags: python

I have this question I hope you could help me..

Basically I have an app where I open a file, read the word from my file and print that word by console. But I want to print "word no found" in case of no finding the word.

Here's my python :

```
import re 

file = open("example.txt","r")
content = file.read()
file.close()
car = re.findall('car\s(.*?)\s',open('example.txt','r').read())
toy = re.findall('toy\s(.*?)\s',open('example.txt','r').read())
print car[0]
print toy[0]
```

here's my text file:

> car red
>
> toy green

I'm getting by console this:

```
red
green
```

Working great as you can see but if I don't have the word "toy" in my file. There's a possible way to get something like this by console :

```
Red
No toy found!
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: `if toy: print toy[0] else: print 'No toy found'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Do not` open the `file` in several locations. It is a bad practice. Open in one  place and use that `object`.

```
content = open('example.txt', 'r').read()
if 'car' in content:
   print("found")
else:
   print("not found")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re 

file = open("example.txt","r")

content = file.read()

file.close()

car = re.findall('car\s(.*?)\s',open('example.txt','r').read())

toy = re.findall('toy\s(.*?)\s',open('example.txt','r').read())

if car == []:
   print "No car found"
else:
   print car[0]

if toy == []:
   print "No toy found"
else:
   print toy[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing `toy[0]` immediately, use an `if-else` statement to check if there is a toy before printing to the console. If there is no toy, print "No toy found".

Based on the code sample you supplied, the solution would look like this:

```
import re 

file = open("example.txt","r")
content = file.read()
file.close()
car = re.findall('car\s(.*?)\s',open('example.txt','r').read())
toy = re.findall('toy\s(.*?)\s',open('example.txt','r').read())
if toy:
    print toy[0]
else:
    print 'No toy found'

if car:
    print car[0]
else:
    print 'No car found'
```

Note that while this solution may work, there are some improvements that can be made to your code overall.
The improvements include:

- Using the Python `with` statement to easily close the file you opened
- Avoid using a variable named `find` as it is a keyword in Python and may lead to unexpected behavior later in your application
- Using the data you've saved in the `content` variable for the regular expression match (so that you don't have to read from the file again).

The improvements will leave you with code that looks like this:
    import re

```
#use with statement to open and close file cleanly
with open('example.txt','r') as f: 
    # save file contents in the content variable so you don't need to open the file again
    content = f.read() 

# use data stored in content variable for your regular expression match
car = re.findall('car\s(.*?)\s',content)
toy = re.findall('toy\s(.*?)\s',content)

if toy:
    print toy[0]
else:
    print 'No toy found'

if car:
    print car[0]
else:
    print 'No car found'
```